# What determines what can be pied-piped and what not in wh-movement?

Tags: questions, wh-questions

- A wh-expression without wh-movement, where the wh-word is the object of the preposition “*about*”:

  > You are talking about **what**?
- A sentence that has undergone wh-movement:

  > **What** are you talking about?
- ⸺with a pied-piped “*about*”:

  > *About **what*** are you talking?
- **A question — This doesn’t seem acceptable; why can’t the “*talking*” get pied-piped as well? Or, can it?**

  > *Talking about **what*** are you?

---

#### Similarly <sub>(I find)</sub>,

[image: From Google search results]

- A wh-expression without wh-movement, where the wh-word is the object of the preposition “*of*”:

  > Chills and headache are symptoms of **what**?
- That above, with wh-movement applied:

  > **What** are chills and headache symptoms of?
- ⸺with a pied-piped “*of*”. **A question — Is this structure acceptable? Why, or why not?**

  > *Of **what*** are chills and headache symptoms?
- The entire wh-clause has gotten pied-piped:

  > *Symptoms of **what*** are chills and headache?

---

Why can’t “-ing about” get pied-piped in wh-movement when “(noun) of” can be? What exactly determines what can be pied-piped and what cannot in wh-movement?

Comment: What is this 'pied-piped' of which you speak?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean [it in the linguistic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping). “A wh-word taking adjacent words together when moved.”

Comment: Rather esoteric for this site. I suggest https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How about “[English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com)?” Do you think this question is better asked in linguistics.stackexchange.com than english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You could give either a try.

Comment: Just to be clear, you should flag for a moderator and ask them to migrate your question to the site where you think it might be a better fit instead of duplicating it. I think it’s fine here, but you may get more responses on another site.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of the question migration process, so I made a duplicate question on English Stack Exchange (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566404/what-determines-what-can-be-pied-piped-and-what-not-in-wh-movement). For this reason, I’m voting to close this question on ELL.